# Continuous Integration that can set up VMs with my Django + PostgreSQL project?

Tags: software-development

I'm looking for an open source Continuous Integration solution that would let me easily define how to build a VM containing my project (pulled from Git) which needs a few pre-run steps. The project is a web application written in Python (Django framework) that employs the PostgreSQL database. I would prefer to spend as little time configuring that as possible.